# Travis CI and Sauce Labs: Can I get Safari working?

Tags: travis-ci, saucelabs

I've got Travis CI working with Sauce Labs on Linux, OS X, and Windows, running tests on Firefox and Chrome. I'd like to get the tests running on Safari as well, but I ran into [this](https://support.saucelabs.com/customer/portal/articles/2005369-testing-with-a-localhost-server-and-some-browsers-can-t-load-my-website). In a nutshell, Safari will only work with a few specific ports for the Sauce Connect proxy, which it appears that Travis CI is not using.

Is there anything I can do to get Travis CI working with Safari on Sauce Labs?